# Move SOFS shares to File Server in general use

Tags: windows, file-server

I have a task to move SOFS shares to FS in general use for cluster server. Unfortunately, I am not expert of Windows Server. Has anybody do this task? I'd like to have help for it and step by step reconfiguration of it. The idea is to delete SOFS shares and create FS shares with the same name. Attach disk where SOFS shares are placed. But what to do with permissions for this shares after reconfiguration?

Thanks in advance for tips.

Additional info:
I have tested some moments of moving from SOFS to FS in general.  1. Created new small disk (1G) for VMs of File Server Cluster, attached it. Initialized it without any letter 2. Added this disk to Disks of Failover Cluster Manager and added it to Cluster Shared Volumes (it assigned to Cluster Shared Volume). 3. Created new role as Scale-Out File Server 4. Created tested 3 shares using new disk. 5. Placed some folders and files in each shares. 6. Removed this role 7. Removed disk from Cluster Shared Volumes (Disk got Available Storage status) 8. Assigned it a drive letter 9. Deleted old name from AD 10. Created new role as FS in general use with same name as it was for SOFS and attached test disk 11. Created new SMB shares with same names as before for SOFS using Type a custom path - choose needed from old shares.
It seems all NTFS permissions for folders and files still presents but I am not abolutely shure (trying to check it).
Shared permissions may be present too but I am not totally sure. That's why I asked before how to get all permissions and implement them after role changing?

Best regards,
Viktor

Answer (score 6):

It won't work in general as SoFS shares have memory cache disabled (except read-only CSV cache) to allow atomic writes for SQL Server and transparent SMB failover for VM live migration. So rather than focusing on permissions which are copied easily with any data migration service like Storage Migration (WS2016+) and Robocopy (WS2003+) (see links below) you should really re-think what you're trying to achieve. TL;DR: Workload working nicely now may break after you move it.

[Use Storage Migration Service to migrate a server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-migration-service/migrate-data)

[Robocopy – File Server Migration](https://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0001233)